# Rerendering a widget that overflows the screen (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating widget which displays the current path in a filesystem to the user.

For example, here is windows file path.
[image]

With each folder opened, the folder name is added to the path. The issue is, when too many folders are added to the path, the Row overflows. Windows solves this by truncating the excess folders to the left
[image]

How can I determine if a widget will overflow, then render it with the overflowing portions removed?

I have tried a method involving calculating the length of the file path using TextPainter, however since my file path widgets are not purely text (icons, padding, etc), the result is rough and does not always work perfectly.

Comment: use `CustomMultiChildLayout` for example (or `Flow` widget)

Comment: @pskink It doesn't seem like CustomMultiChildLayout can depend on its childrens size, can you provide an example of how you would implement that?

Comment: cannot you return a `Size` with some fixed height from `Size MultiChildLayoutDelegate.getSize(BoxConstraints constraints)` method? for example a default text size multiplied by some factor 1.5 or something? or size of the icon you want to use in the children?

Comment: but if you cannot return such fixed height (and need to return the max  height from children) you need to implement a custom `RenderBox` - see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderBox-class.html for more info (read "Using ContainerRenderObjectMixin" section in particular)

Comment: @pskink every child in the MultiChildLayout needs to have layoutChild called on it. In my case, I want some of the children to not be rendered, so I wouldn't call layoutChild on it. So it wouldn't quite work in my scenario. I think making a custom RenderBox is the solution, if you could provide an example of that as an answer I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @pskink I tried to implement it again and got it working! Thank you!

Comment: good! btw I forgot that with `Flow` widget you don't have to call `paintChild` on every child

Comment: also feel free to post your solution as a self answer so other people could benefit from it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global key in your widget which will tell you the size of your current widget.

```
GlobalKey stickyKey = GlobalKey();
Container(
  key: _widgetKey,
),
```

Then just use it wherever you want:

```
 void _getWidgetInfo(_) {
    final RenderBox renderBox = _widgetKey.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
 
    final Size size = renderBox.size; // or _widgetKey.currentContext?.size
    print('Size: ${size.width}, ${size.height}');
 
    final Offset offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    print('Offset: ${offset.dx}, ${offset.dy}');
    print('Position: ${(offset.dx + size.width) / 2}, ${(offset.dy + size.height) / 2}');
  }
```

I'm guessing you have a method which you call whenever you move on to the new folder then just call `_getWidgetInfo` mehtod whenever you move on to calculate the new lenght.

Comment: Wouldn't a global key only be useful if I had the widget already rendered? I'm not sure how I can use it to determine if the width will overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you? It'll trim/crop the contents on the left/starting to fill the all available right/end contents.

**Output:**

[image]

**Complete code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const CodeCyanApp());

class CodeCyanApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const CodeCyanApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const Icon(Icons.folder),
            const SizedBox(width: 5),
            Expanded(
              child: Stack(
                alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerEnd,
                children: [
                  Positioned(
                    top: 0,
                    child: Wrap(
                      spacing: 5,
                      children: const [
                        Text('>'),
                        Text('Windows'),
                        Text('>'),
                        Text('Programs'),
                        Text('>'),
                        Text('CodeCyan'),
                        Text('>'),
                        Text('Utilities'),
                        Text('>'),
                        Text('Flutter'),
                        Text('>'),
                        Text('Wrap'),
                        Text('>'),
                        Text('Neted'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 5),
            const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
            const SizedBox(width: 5),
            const Icon(Icons.refresh),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It is a clever idea, but the clipping on the left wouldn't fit well with my design.